# PHP - basic phone number validation

Tags: php

I'm trying to validate for UK phone numbers - the specific requirements I have are:

- must only consist of digits
- the only non-digit characters allowed are space and dash
- must begin with a zero

Can anyone suggest a nice and simple regular expression I can use for this?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Please include your attempts in the question itself.

Comment: what about +44 (0)1234 567891 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following regex:

```
^0([ -]\d+)*\d+$
```

Comment: Cheers that didn't quite work, but this did: `^0(\d+[ -])*\d+$`